# How to prevent a .command file from showing window when it runs on OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-snow-leopard, terminal, osx-lion

If you have a .command file on your desktop containing say a Terminal command that it runs when you double click it, is there anyway to either (1) prevent the window that pops open when you run it, or (2) close the window automatically when the process is complete?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and actually just want your Firefox launching script to work in the background, is that correct? :) — the question is if you still need an answer for *this* question then.

Comment: @slhck Yes that is correct. If using automator in my other question works, then I really do not need an answer to this one. Although could this still be a valid question that somebody else may want answered? I am actually curious now if this is possible even if I don't need to use it! Thanks

Comment: Automator did work: here was the other question:
http://superuser.com/questions/397277/how-to-run-bash-profile-function-from-desktop-alias-command-file-on-osx-lion/397297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about running it 'in the background', but it's possible to close the window after the execution is complete, as said here: [How do I close the Terminal in OSX from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/158375/how-do-i-close-the-terminal-in-osx-from-the-command-line)

Just open Terminal and go to `Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Shell: > When the shell exits: -> Close if the shell exited cleanly`

Then just add `exit;` at the end of your file.

Comment: @"Jack BeePee" Thanks... that's good to know!